# Blocking button when input textbox is empty asp.Net webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a button and text control on my page.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="MyText" Width="100%" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" OnClientClick="isNotEmpty()" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Send_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" />
```

I am trying to make sure that it won't trigger OnClick if the textBox on the page is empty (or has whitespace). My code does not work and I have no clue why.

```
function isNotEmpty() {
      if (<%= MyText.Text.Length %> > 0)
        return true;
       return false;
    }
```

I also tried:

```
function isNotEmpty(){
  document.getElementbyId("MyText").value !== null || document.getElementbyId("MyText").value.match(/^\s*$/) === null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `return`  in `OnClientClick`

```
<asp:Button ID="MyButton" OnClientClick="return isNotEmpty();" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="Send_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" CausesValidation="false" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to locate the `MyText` control on the client, unfortunately its name is not `"MyText"`. It's assigned by the server and can differ based on what other elements surround it.

```
function isNotEmpty(){
   var textBox = document.getElementbyId("<%= MyText.ClientID %>");
   return textBox.value !== null || textBox.value.match(/^\s*$/) === null;
}
```

You also need to incorporate Agalo's answer into the ASPX file.

> `OnClientClick="return isNotEmpty();"`

Comment: I did that but still the OnClick always fires :(

Comment: Debug the JS to make sure it's returning false. Try `return false;` in your `OnClientClick` and see if it's still posting, it should not be.